# Detecting HTML5 with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I need to make sure my code works fine in all browsers html or html5.
My code in Firefox and Chrome is working fine, but in IE I have problem. I want to fix them...

If the client supports HTML5, and this set of codes. If not, do something else.

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://modernizr.com/

Comment: can you show some of your code? we'll be able to identify anything that will be an issue in certain browsers.

Comment: @scunliffe , for the example , fullscreen api . thats not working on IE, i want do some thing else, and be sure its not HTML5 , thx for quick answer.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to test for "HTML5 support" since HTML5 is a collection of several totally separate APIs. What you want is "feature detection" -- you want to test if a *specific feature* of HTML5 is supported. Modrnizr (linked above) is perfect for that.

Comment: @apsillers ! thats my answer ! i need fullscreen API , and if i wont to use Modrnizr , how can i do that?

Answer (score 5):

There is a feature detection library called [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) that can help.

Here is an example from their documentation:

```
Modernizr.load({
  test: Modernizr.geolocation,
  yep : 'geo.js',
  nope: 'geo-polyfill.js'
});
```

The `yep` condition is the script to load if geolocation is available. The `nope` condition is the script to load if it is not available - which would contain your alternative / polyfill.

You want to test the exact thing you want to use, rather than whether HTML5 is supported or not. This is because HTML5 may be partially supported by a browser - but also because many features are in fact not HTML5 at all, but a separate specification. (Geolocation is not part of the HTML5 specification).

Answer (score 1):

There are issues with html5 when implementing with Internet Explorer. Most of the problem you will face arise from the css3. To handle this you can manually change the css, or include a  like HTML5 Shiv.
This is the URL you need to include.

```
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>

$("body").append(innerShiv("<section></section>"));
```

The above said links are also good

Answer (score -1):

Dear This is simple function. You can detect if browser support html5 or not with out help of any library.

```
<script>
var test_canvas = document.createElement("canvas") //try and create sample canvas element
var canvascheck=(test_canvas.getContext)? true : false //check if object supports getContext() method, a method of the canvas element
if(canvascheck == true)
{
    alert("This browser support html5");
}
else{

     alert("This browser does not support html5");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Supporting canvas !== supporting HTML5.

Comment: You should feature detect the feature you want to use, not base your detection off of a different feature. Also, the "main" element of HTML5 is actually `<main>`, which is only supported in the latest versions of Opera and Chrome currently. Yes, that was tongue in cheek (but factually correct).